# What is mean of × in SAM?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolov4

I would like to understand SAM, the model during YOLOv4.
However, I am confused as to the meaning of the "x" in the diagram.
Please tell me what module name this "x" represents in yolov4.cfg in darknet.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is element-wise multiplication, so in most of the libraries quite literally the `*`. Source is here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06521.pdf

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.
Which layer of src/parse.c should I use to reproduce this element-wise multiplication in the darknet cfg? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to.  This is literally basic operation of "take 2 matrices of the same shape and output a new matrix with multiplication of corresponding elements". Not sure what do you mean by "layer to reproduce it".

Comment: What I meant to say is that I was asking which one corresponds to multiplication in the name of the layer in the cfg in darkent.
For example, "conv" for convolution, "yolo" for yolo, etc.

Comment: cfg URl : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4.cfg

Comment: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-different-layers according to this documentation "SAM" is the layer that does the multiplication. You probably want https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-sam-mish-csp-reorg-bfm.cfg, see https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/YOLOv4-model-zoo